# Is there a relatively straight forward way to make a note of all applications/programs installed on my mac for future reference?

Tags: applications

Is there a relatively straight forward way to make a note of all applications/programs installed on my mac for future reference, without having to note down each application one by one via word etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open `/Applications` in the Finder
- Press <kbd>Cmd-A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Cmd-C</kbd>
- Switch to Pages/Word/TextEdit/etc.
- Create a new document and press <kbd>Cmd-V</kbd>

Repeat for sub-folders of /Applications and any other place (~/Applications maybe) where you have installed applications.

Comment: Hi Patrix thanks very much for that, as far as i'm aware I think 90% of my Apps are in the Applications folder, although I have noticed a few when I go into system preferernces right at the bottom such as Avast, Flip WMV. Not quite sure what they are doing there !

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. The usual way to say "thank you" is the upvote button :-). To your followup question: System extensions of any kind are usually installed in /Library or ~/Library, but they are more difficult to collect afterwards.

Comment: Ah yes that right, these are known as system extensions :).

Comment: Do I click on the tick button as well, or do people just add comments and there input as they please?

Comment: Upvote -> I like this answer/good answer/good idea/thank you. You can upvote as many answers as you like, also on questions others have asked. Accept -> I accept this as the answer to my question. Only for your own questions and only one per question. Comments can be added anytime.

Comment: I clicked on the tick and it has now turned green, i clicked on the upvote (but no sure what happened)

Comment: It says in order to vote up I need "15 reputation", so I dont think I can vote up just yet, as I'm new to this forum !

Comment: Read the FAQ, vote for some other questions/answers you like or fill out your profile to get more reputation.

Comment: this did not work for me.  E.g. i just installed Sublime Text and it is not showing in the list even after doing `Cmd-A` followed by `Cmd-C`